# iOS - Does AVFoundation support 3D Barcodes?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, barcode, barcode-scanner

The documentation and the header file does not contain any information related to support of 3D barcodes. However, explicitly mentions AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject supports one-dimensional and two-dimensional barcodes. Therefore, does anybody know 3D Barcodes are supported by AVFoundation ?

Comment: To be precise, do you mean Color Construct Code (Color C Code)? http://2d-code.co.uk/color-code-technologies/

Comment: Official [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataobject.objecttype) contains no references to "Color C Code". Though DataMatrix looks similar, but in black&white. Maybe there is a way to write custom data detector?

Answer (score 0):

Supported QRCodes by AVFoundation are upce,code39,Code 39 mod 43,EAN-13,EAN-8,code93,code128,pdf417,Interleaved 2 of 5,ITF14,DataMatrix ,Aztec & All of them are 1d/2d .https://www.scandit.com/types-barcodes-choosing-right-barcode/

If we try to go into detail of 3d bar codes which are called Custom QR Codes, The bars in a 3D barcode are read by a scanner that reads the differences in the height of each line .http://www.qrcodestickers.org/qr-code-articles/3D-barcodes.html.